# Get parent document origin for cross-domain HTTPS iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

I want to read `window.top.location.origin` from inside an iFrame.
The parent and iFrame are on different HTTPS domains.
Trying to access that throws a security error in Chrome for example.
`[DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.]`

Is it at all possible to do that without triggering the error?

I need `window.top`'s origin because I send different postMessages based on that origin.

Comment: what kind of error do you get in the console?

Comment: I'll update the question.

Comment: you need to get a message from the parent, and then you can see the origin from the message properties. it's like replying to an email you didn't used to have the address for.

Comment: Yup, I know that. But I'm trying do initiate the communication from the child iFrame. e.g. "I'm loaded and ready to listen for events"

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old, but maybe it helps others:

The full Parent URL will appear to the `<iframe/>` as `document.referrer`. With that, you can parse it locally to find the URL specifics you may need.

```
if (document.referrer !== location.href) {
  let foo = document.createElement('a');
  foo.href = document.referrer;
  console.log('origin is:', foo.origin);
}
```

Of course, this is thanks to the anchor tag's built-in parsing. Hidden gem~!

Answer (score 0):

Because of the same-origin policy, JavaScript in an iframe from a different origin will not be able to communicate with its parent frame. If you have access to the server that serves the iframe, you can enable CORS, otherwise I think you are out of luck

Comment: That's not true. You can communicate using `postMessage`.
However, my question was about getting the domain for the parent iFrame.